# content security policy missing protocol/scheme for host/domain, is it secure?

Tags: https, protocols, content-security-policy, url-scheme

I got this CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com; frame-src 'self'; font-src data: fonts.gstatic.com 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';
```

For example, fonts.googleapis.com does not have a scheme or protocol (https: absent). Does it automatically mean that it is over secure HTTPs (if the current page/source is)? And would it be vulnerable to MiTM attacks? I think the documentation is not clear to me (the CSP evaluator of Google says 'Good')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it automatically mean that it is over secure HTTPs (if the current page/source is)?

Yes, schemeless host-source means that browser will follow the Same Origin Policy to restore actual scheme.
Therefore if page is loaded via HTTPS - all schemeless host-sources in CSP obtains `https://` scheme.
And on HTTP-page all schemeless host-sources in CSP obtains `http://` scheme, all nitty-gritty is [here](https://csplite.com/csp/test150/).

> And would it be vulnerable to MiTM attacks?

It would be vulnerable only on HTTP-pages. Any HTTP page is vulnerable to MiTM, and a lot of russian ISPs [still injects their Ads](https://csplite.com/csp300/) into customer visited pages using MiTM on HTTP.

Why don't you worried about `'self'` usage? The `'self'` means `http://example.com` on HTTP-page and `https://example.com` on HTTPS pages. So it's vulnerable the same way as schemeless `fonts.googleapis.com` usage.

**BTW** why do you load fonts from Google's CDN in 2021? This slow the site: [1](https://sia.codes/posts/making-google-fonts-faster/), [2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/fast-google-fonts-with-cloudflare-workers/) and do not cached by browsers. Use https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts to extract fonts and store its locally and then use `<link rel="preload" as="font" ...` preloading.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about hosting fonts myself.